# Composite WHERE clause in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

In Markus Winand's blog post [Pagination done the Postgresql way](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way) the following appears on slide 22:

```
select * from <table> where topic = 1234 
and (date, id) < (prev_date, prev_id)
order by date desc, id desc
limit 10;
```

This uses a composite value (or "row value") in the `WHERE` clause, which in 2013 was apparently only supported by Postgres.  With correct indexing this should be more efficient than the `OFFSET`/`LIMIT` anti-pattern.

Is there any way of performing this type of `WHERE` clause in a sqlalchemy filter?  My searches so far have only found information about composite keys.

Comment: The linked question is helpful, however it is primarily concerned with the `in` function. I don’t see a way to map that to operators like `>` or `<`.

Comment: `tuple_(t.c.a, t.c.b) < (1, 2)` or `tuple_(...) < tuple_(...)` depending on whether or not you're using literals etc. It's not that big a leap, when you understand how SQLA overrides operators.